# What is the quickest and easiest way to run a small php script on my html page?

Tags: php, html, scripting

What is the quickest and easiest way to run a small php script on my html page and what do I need to do to get it running? I'm asking because I use html and css all the time, but have never done anything in php. I'll be using it to create an email form that doesn't open an email client to send it.

Comment: @Russell, you can read about what quarkdown27 is talking about on the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but www.php.net is a good resource to get started with PHP,

Comment: @cromestant - What? If he doesn't know then someone needs to tell him. Quark was being both polite and helpful, and heeding his advice will help Russell get more/better answers in the future.

Comment: @kenwhite true he did not decline to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your host needs to support PHP.  Most do.

Make a basic script like this:

```
<?php
    mail('your@email.com', 'Some Subject', print_r($_POST, true));
?>
```

Then, build yourself an HTML form that points to this script...

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="SomeField" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

That's all there is to it.  **HOWEVER**, this is problematic.  You will get spam.  You need to implement CAPTCHA and such.  Otherwise you will get e-mails all the time, even if someone just hits this script with their web browser and no POST data.

[Read a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772349/what-is-a-good-online-tutorial-for-php) and learn some PHP.  It will help you in the long run.

There is also a [great form example on tizag.com](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formex.php) that will help you understand the components at work here.  Basically, you have an HTML form with a few fields (SomeField, submit) and when someone submits this form it will send the data to yourscript.php via the POST method.  The PHP script can then read the data in the [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).  PHP has a convenient [`mail()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function that is great for sending basic e-mail messages.  The [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function is used to show everything in an array, such as $_POST.

Comment: This is a good answer. I'd like to further it by suggesting you find a good mail script that has security and validation built in, preferably one you can read and understand how it works. Also I feel obligated to express my distaste for CAPTCHAs. They work, but there are also more transparent options. I consider them a last resort.

Comment: @Syntax Error, I too hate CAPTCHA, but haven't found a good alternative.  Do you have a suggestion?  For awhile we were using some Javascript to render the form.  This greatly cut down on spam for years, but there are a few bots that have learned, and they seem to send quite a bit, at least on our site.  We went back to CAPTCHA.  Even though these are easily broken by computers, it seems nobody is trying.

Comment: What if you included a random value as a hidden field in the form, then checked to make sure the form was submitted with that same value (by saving it in the session)?  That would at least prevent people from running the yourscript.php by just requesting in their browser.

Comment: @Michael, this example is just to get Russell started, and isn't meant to be a final solution.  If you want to prevent people from running the script just by hitting it with their browser directly, just test `empty($_POST)`.

Comment: Some of my CAPTCHA alternatives - various tests on form fields set to display:none via CSS, checking the page load time vs the form submission time to see if it was too fast for a human to type, checks for a couple extremely common phrases I see in spam, checking for bbcode in the message field if there is no reason for it to be there, also I have been wanting to implement a check to see if the email address they used actually exists. I know none are foolproof, but used together they are highly effective unless you are a valuable enough target for someone to spend much human time on.

Comment: Also you can do similar things, and even make them more strict, but instead of denying the email testing positive triggers the CAPTCHA. This gets rid of the possibility of false positives while making things easier on some of your users.

Comment: Cool, I hadn't thought of `display:none`.  That's a good one!  I think I might implement this on our sites tomorrow.

Comment: Great answer. Though my main question is not how to code specific things in PHP. I wrote some scripts a few weeks ago that should have worked but didn't. When I asked a friend about it, he told me that I needed to have a PHP server running. So my question is how do I setup the server and configure to run PHP.

Comment: Well, that is a very different question asked, or at least answered.  I recommend actually creating a new question over on serverfault.com, just so it doesn't get so confusing.  Make sure to include what web server you are using.  It isn't too difficult though.  You can download PHP here:  http://www.php.net/downloads.php  Installation instructions here:  http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

Answer (score 0):

well, the form itself is html, your form will post ( or GET) to your php script and this will send the email and show output.

To execute the php script you need a webserver that supports php (IIS with the php module, apache with php module etc). Your webserver will host the script and then will execute it and return the output to the browser.
Also you need access to an SMTP server in order to send the email.
Look at php mail for basic usage, and mostly [pear mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected) for a more complete solution ( including smtp auth).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have php installed and configured properly with your server. Then it's as easy as this:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

Edit: Also, you may need to use the file extension .php on the page you are trying to run the script on. For example index.php - It may or may not work if the extension is .html

Does that work? If so you are ready to make your script. If not please provide more information about your hosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

The .php file is translated just like a normal HTML page if you don't use the opening tag for PHP (), so you can just have normal HTML, and put the PHP somewhere on the page in tags.